# Can i use same name application on playstore?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, android-package-managers

Please tell me can I use same name in google playstore of application. Actually i bought an application from online site. Some of people use unique name of application just like as mine but they are using different package name. So i want to know can i use also same name of application or not?

Comment: yes But Package Name Not Some App Name Ia allowed

Comment: Yes. But then how would a user distinguish between **your app** an another one with the **same name**?! I get easily bored, when I search (for instance) "Sound Recorder" and I get 20 apps with the same name!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application can have the same title as many others with no problem. 
As for the package name, it must be unique because it works as your application id on the Market. Once you publish your app, you cannot change your package name.